# ERC777 AuthorizeOperator function

Tags: solidity, erc-777

I was implementing some functionalities of ERC777 and need some help with the Authorize Operator function.
Does this function approves for all the ERC20 tokens present within a wallet or the operator gets assigned for some specific address tokens.

Also, if you could comment any good resources for ERC777 implementation, it would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERC777 standard can permit you to create a token and transfer it without two transaction (approve() and transferFrom() like ERC20 standard).

So, ERC777  use the operator to authorize to spend a specific token!

The operator cannot spend other tokens when they don't authorized!

See in this [link](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/simple-erc777-token-example/746) for more information to implement ERC777 on your smart contract.

More information on the [documentation](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777).